# SELECT with LEFT JOIN performing math operation twice?

Tags: sql, oracle

The general idea of what I'm trying to do is this:
Select all planned prices for an order, then subtract from that total all actual prices on that order.

The planned price and actual price are on different tables. When I have a single planned price and a single actual price, this works fine. However, when I have multiple planned prices or multiple actual prices it is giving me odd results as if the algebra is happening multiple times.

Query:

```
    SELECT PL.orderid, (SUM(PL.lineprice) - NVL(SUM(AC.lineprice),0)) AS 
    Difference FROM plans PL
    LEFT JOIN actuals AC ON PL.orderid = AC.orderid
    WHERE PL.customer IN (SELECT customer FROM ...)
    GROUP BY PL.orderid
    ORDER BY PL.orderid;
```

The results of the query:

```
Orderid Difference
X-1224      100
X-1226      80
X-1345      70000
X-1351      125000
X-1352      10000
Y-2403      190000
```

My Plan table looks like this:

```
Orderid Planned_Price
X-1224      100
X-1226      100
X-1345      105000
X-1351      100000
X-1352      10000
X-1352      50000
Y-2403      25000
Y-2403      100000
```

And my Actual table this:

```
Orderid Actual_Price
X-1226      20
X-1345      35000
X-1351      25000
X-1351      50000
X-1352      25000
Y-2403      25000
Y-2403      5000
```

So it seems to work when I have only a single row in each table, or a single row in plans and no rows in actuals *i.e., X-1224, X-1226 and X-1345*.

However the results are too high or too low when I have multiple rows, with the same OrderID, in either table *i.e., all the rest*

I'm stumped as to why this is the case. Any insights are appreciated.

**edit: Results I'd like, taking Y-2403 as example: (25000 + 100000) - (25000 + 5000) = 95000.** What I'm getting is double that at 190000.

Comment: Check the computation. (25000+100000)-(25000+5000)=95000 is correct?

Comment: Yes the math is correct. 100+25 = 125. 25+5 = 30. 125 - 30 = 95. What I can't seem to figure out is how to take the aggregate the Plan_Price and Actual_Price from their respective tables independently then join those results together to always make the math work out correctly.

As I mentioned with your solution below, the math still comes out incorrect if Plans has more entries for an Order than Actuals does.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this the case?

Because that is how `join` works.  If you have data like this:

```
 a
 1
 1
 2
 2
```

And b:

```
 b
 1
 1
 1
 2
```

Then the result of a `join` will have six "1"s and two "2"s.

Your question doesn't say what you want for results, but a typical approach is to aggregate *before* doing the joins.

EDIT:

You seem to want:

```
select p.orderid,
       (p.lineprice - coalesce(lineprice, 0)) as Difference
from (select orderid, sum(lineprice) as lineprice
      from plans p
      group by orderid
     ) p left join
    (select orderid, sum(lineprice) as lineprice
     from actuals a
     group by orderid
    ) a
    on p.orderid = a.orderid
where p.customer in (SELECT customer FROM ...)
order by p.orderid;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. So the results I was hoping for, take Y-2403 as example would be: (100000 + 25000) - (25000 + 5000) = 95000. The result of the query though is double that, at 190000.

So you're saying I should perform the aggregation separately on each table, then use both of these as sub-queries to some outer query where I perform the subtraction?

Comment: @omar . . . Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: how does one do that? I can't figure out how to sum my prices from each table independently then join those results together to take the difference of SUM(Plan_Price) - SUM(Actual_Price)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking to compare the summed_up_prices by order id of plan table with the summed_up prices by order id actual plan table.?

If so the following can be done to ensure there are no duplicates entries by order

```
select a.orderid
       ,NVL(max(b.summed_up),0) - sum(a.actual_price) as difference          
     from actual_table a
left join (select pt.orderid
                 ,sum(pt.planned_price) as summed_up
            from planned_table pt
           group by pt.orderid
           )b
        on a.orderid=b.orderid
  group by a.orderid

+---------+------------+
| ORDERID | DIFFERENCE |
+---------+------------+
| X-1226  |         80 |
| Y-2403  |      95000 |
| X-1351  |      25000 |
| X-1345  |      70000 |
| X-1352  |      35000 |
+---------+------------+
```

Here is the dbfiddle link with the data

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3cacffd19b39ecaf7ad752dff262ac47

Comment: So I tried this (my order is reversed with the queries and subtraction being Plan - Actual but same form) and I'm still seeing odd results.

When the Plans table has 2 entries but Actual only 1, I can get a negative number. For instance if Plans has 10 and 5 as entries, Actuals has 10 then my result is -5 instead of the expected +5. I think I need to use both of these queries independently and then LEFT JOIN the results, does that sound right?

Comment: I haved edited my query as follows. It  now does the summing up based on the planned_table and actual_table and performs the difference. You can see the difference for Y-2403 the value shown up is 95000

Comment: You're a genius, thank you! It seems the key was changing the function inside of the NVL to MAX() instead of SUM(). I ran tests with more rows in the Plans table per Ordierid, more in the Actual table per Orderid, and situations where the Difference should be positive or negative and it all works! I'm not quite sure why MAX() fixed it, but I'll do some reading on W3schools to try and figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: The query output of the block "b" would be all unique orderid. which means all of those records would have exactly one summed_up value.  Now in the outer block "a" i am joining on by a.orderid and grouping by a.orderid. and so i would need to use any aggregate function (i used max, min/avg would also work here), for selecting a non-grouped by element(ie b.summed_up). That is the reason why i used MAX(b.summed_up)

Comment: I understand the need for an aggregate function, and I see that MIN/AVG both also return the same results, but why does SUM not? My understanding is that it is also an aggregate function. Thank you again for your answer and explanations.